# Read (log)file without locking renaming/moving for other processes

Tags: java, file-io

i have to read log-files at the moment they are written. the problem is, this log-files will be renamed at some point in time and i have to guarantee that this renaming operation is possible/ the java reading process is not locking it.

how to do this

Comment: While Java is cross-platform, this issue is really OS-dependent. Linux, for example, won't lock the file by default. You are free to move or even delete it while it is open for reading. I don't know any workaround for Windows, though, so I can't really answer this (good) question.

Comment: But the use case: "read log files while they are growing and being renamed sometimes" should be prevalent, shouldn't it? What can i do, minimizing the time of the lock? Reading only the last line -how?

Comment: "Minimizing" is not really a good idea, although it is possible to implement using random access reading. But this way you'll only make a bug that is hard to reproduce. If the reading process knows renaming logic, it could avoid opening file if it is about to be renamed. But it is kind of semi-workaround which may or may not work depending on the logic in question. The best thing you can do is to make renaming process just try again and again if rename fails, so it won't be a fatal error. But it works only if you have control over it.

Comment: thx, you are absolutely right. "minimizing" only makes sense together with a tolerant renaming algorithm - retrying the renaming at some time an not being angry if it fails. The problem is i don't have control over it. at the moment there is only a "magic number" - the log files size is 10mb at max. the algorithm implemented now knows this size and stops reading some bytes before this size then it waits for the file to be renamed. the problem is sometimes the writing process stops writing within this "some bytes" - and the algorithm waits "forever".

Comment: If it renamed at certain time, it would be much easier. But since it does it based on the file size, I can't imagine any workaround. I couldn't find a way to open file without locking it using Java either.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy to RAM and read from copy

Comment: this would implement the "minimizing the time of the lock"- approach, wouldn't it? Ignoring Sergey's comment for a moment ("But this way you'll only make a bug that is hard to reproduce.") How to implement this? I tried "randomaccessfile" with reverse reading. but as long i am reading, i can't rename the file. What is the fastest way to copy a file or a part of to memory and reading the memory?